# Django Multi-Database support

Tags: python, django, multi-database

NB: I have already gone through the Django official documentation here docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db, but nothing on the page answers my questions.

I have led a team to develop two Django web applications and we have reached a stage where we would like to make features on each of the sites available to one another. By so doing, we would have adhered to the DRY principle.

## Case Study

Site A has A+ features and i would love to make it available on site B, through Django Queryset, and vice versa.

## So far

I have defined in the settings.py file for both sites the database configurations, added a generic Router configuration for all the apps with the help of this post: http://diegobz.net/2011/02/10/django-database-router-using-settings/  and can successfully query the databases for A and B from both sites using from django.db import connections. However, with the below:

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    desc = cursor.description
    return[
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
        ]
```

i get lists of objects' data and not Querysets.

## Question

1. Is this the right away to go about the problem described above?
2. Is there a way to import/return Querysets/iterable Model objects using the implementation described above?
3. Are there APIs out there that can handle Django Multi-databases connection? If yes, please provide links?

Thank you for your time.

## My Solution (for now)

It seems the strategy i was planning to use before was kind of an overkill. So, i decided to adopt a different strategy. However, it seems to get me half-way but i foresee it leading to DRY.

The solution is to have REST-APIs on both sites return data in json format.

i.e call API of site A, load the returned data and process it in site B.

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Yes, i have. I'm not sure i would have been able to get this far without first going through the link you have provided. Meanwhile, nothing on the page answers my questions. Thanks